# How to continuously train our pre-trained model on real time data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have some sensors which fetch data from cement factory and sends data to AWS IoT. The data is then tested on pre-trained model and the model predicts quality of cement based on some parameters. The data is coming in one second interval.

Since the data is coming in real-time, I want to train the model incrementally in real time.

Can anybody suggest how train model continuously?

Comment: Look at Apache Flink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could aggregate certain numbers of training data and then use `.partial_fit()` to update your model.

[`.partial_fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) is the incremental learning option, which is available in Sklearn.

If your incremental data would not fit in RAM, then its worth trying [dask-ml wrapper for incremental learning](https://ml.dask.org/incremental.html#incremental-meta-estimator).